# Selenium Webdriver with Python: Avoiding multiple logins in my test

Tags: python, selenium

At the moment , my test code is calling sign_in() function every time the test for a particular page passes , I want to login once and complete the test for all the pages so that it takes less time to complete the test. Attached is the code from base class and one of the test page.
//this is the base test class
import unittest2
from selenium import webdriver

class BaseTestClass(unittest2.TestCase):

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    """Setups the connection to selenium and defines the broswer in use"""
    #cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    cls.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://bs-sel01.lonres.lan:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
    cls.test_instance = cls.my_test_class(cls.driver)
    cls.url = cls.driver.current_url
    # Window for main test. At this point the first window is always the main window
    cls.main_window = cls.driver.window_handles[0]


def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.driver.get(self.url)

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()

def tearDown(self):
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
    # After a test fixture we close all browsers except the main window
    for handle in self.driver.window_handles:
        if handle != self.main_window:
            self.driver.switch_to_window(handle)
            self.driver.close()
    self.driver.switch_to_window(self.main_window)
```

//this is one of the test pages

from selenium import webdriver
from base_test_class import BaseTestClass
from pages import PAGE_TITLES, ParkingSpacesPage
from public_site_pages import PublicSiteHomePage

#

class TestParkingSpacesPage(BaseTestClass):
    my_test_class = PublicSiteHomePage

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(TestParkingSpacesPage, cls).setUpClass()
    cls.test_instance = cls.test_instance.sign_in(ParkingSpacesPage)
    cls.url = cls.driver.current_url

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_property_address_link(self):
    """property address link on Parking space page"""
    post_code = self.test_instance.property_address_link()

    self.driver.implicitly_wait(800)
    self.assertIn("%s - Google Maps" % post_code.replace(u'\xa0', u' '), self.driver.title)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_postcode_link(self):
    """postcode link on Parking space page"""
    post_code = self.test_instance.postcode_link()
    self.assertIn("%s - Google Maps" % post_code.replace(u'\xa0', u' '), self.driver.title)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_agent_name_link(self):
    """agent name link on Parking space page"""
    element = self.test_instance.agent_name_link()
    #confirm if name of property appears in new window title e.g "Lonres.com: Flat 9, 110 frampton Street, NW10"
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(800)
    assert ("Lonres.com: %s" % element) in self.driver.title

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#the property needs to have at least one photo
def test_view_pic_link(self):
    """view picture link on Parking space page"""
    self.test_instance.view_pic_link()

    self.driver.implicitly_wait(800)
    self.assertIn(PAGE_TITLES["LonresPhotosPage"], self.driver.title)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_send_to_mobile(self):
    """Send to mobile link on Parking space page"""
    self.test_instance.send_to_mobile_link()

    self.driver.implicitly_wait(800)
    self.assertIn(PAGE_TITLES["LonresSendMobilePhonePage"], self.driver.title)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_thumbnail_image_link(self):
    """photo link on Parking space page"""
    self.test_instance.image_thumbnail_link()

    self.driver.implicitly_wait(800)
    self.assertIn(PAGE_TITLES["LonresPhotosPage"], self.driver.title)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_send_valid_email(self):
    """This test sends a mail with a valid email address"""
    #check if we are on the test environment
    environment = 'https://test.lonres.lan'
    if environment not in self.driver.current_url:
        self.skipTest("This test is built to run on only https://test.lonres.lan")

    to_address = 'igba@lonres.com'
    index = 1
    email_page = self.test_instance.send_email(index)
    cc_address = email_page.get_cc_address()
    email_page.set_to_address(to_address)
    email_subject = email_page.get_email_subject()
    message_payload = email_page.send_email()
    self.assertIn('Lonres.com: Email Sent', self.driver.title)
    #inspect message payload
    self.assertEquals(to_address, message_payload['to'])
    self.assertEquals('Selenium Tester <igbaujege.lonrescomlimited@agentparticulars.com>', message_payload['from'])
    self.assertEquals(cc_address, message_payload['cc'])
    self.assertEquals(email_subject, message_payload['subject'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to do this?  Self contained atomic tests are easier to debug and understand failures.

Tests which rely on other tests to leave the system in the right state are brittle and unreliable.

If test runtime is an issue, perhaps you should consider parallel running of your tests using Selenium Grid?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global boolean `hasSignedIn = false`

And then in each test, sign in only if necessary.

```
if not (hasSignedIn):
    sign_in()
```

Then you can avoid signing in whenever possible, without depending on other tests. It takes only milliseconds to check the boolean, so that should save time.

Comment: Actual: what we have implemented at the moment is we sign in run the test for a particular page and then to run the test for another page, it logs you out and then again login and perform the test for another page. Expected: we would like to sign in once , complete the tests of one page , then move to another page without signing out till we complete tests for all the pages.